# Update certificate on windows iot core without Azure IoT hub

Tags: windows-iot-core-10

We have a Windows `IoT` device without internet connection. How can we update a `SSL` certificate the same way as in `Azure IoT Hub`.

[Set up X.509 security in your Azure IoT hub](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-security-x509-get-started)

How can we do this in C#?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer to following code.[CertificateEnrollmentManager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.security.cryptography.certificates.certificateenrollmentmanager) can be used to import a certificate from a Personal Information Exchange (PFX) message. Firstly, you need to read the remote file from uri, parse the buffer to base64 string, and then import the certificate to your store.

```
            string pfxCertificate = null;
            string pfxPassword = "";

            var remoteUri = "http://XXXXXXXX";
            IRandomAccessStreamReference thumbnail = RandomAccessStreamReference.CreateFromUri(new Uri(remoteUri));
            file = await Windows.Storage.StorageFile.CreateStreamedFileFromUriAsync(".pdf",new Uri(remoteUri), thumbnail);

            var buffer = await Windows.Storage.FileIO.ReadBufferAsync(file);
            using (DataReader dataReader = DataReader.FromBuffer(buffer))
            {
                byte[] bytes = new byte[buffer.Length];
                dataReader.ReadBytes(bytes);
                // convert to Base64 for using with ImportPfx
                pfxCertificate = System.Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
            }

            await CertificateEnrollmentManager.UserCertificateEnrollmentManager.ImportPfxDataAsync(
                        pfxCertificate,
                        pfxPassword,
                        ExportOption.NotExportable,
                        KeyProtectionLevel.NoConsent,
                        InstallOptions.None,
                        "Test");
```